# How can I have different rules on pregmatch?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

Let's assume we have couple of inputs:
1-west:726435632:9236
2-west:8463758:873648
green:8234682:92347
red:98374:98374
H09

For output I want to have:
1. if it was anything other than H, just pass the first part like
1-west:283647873:86324873---->1-west

2. if it was anything started with H, pass HOLDING as output:
   H06--->HOLDING

Can anybody help me how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this ?

```
function check($string) {
    $test = preg_match('/^H./', $string);
    if ($test) {
        return 'HOLDING';
    }
    $parts = explode(':', $string);
    return $parts[0];
}
```

Or in one line (assuming `$input` contains your input)

```
$output = preg_match('/^H./', $input) ? 'HOLDING' : substr($input, 0, strpos($input, ":"));
```

Comment: I want to have this somehow in one pregmatch line. is that possible?

Comment: preg_match will tell you if the pattern matched or not, you can probably re-write this in one line using ternary operator. Will that do ?

Comment: the one line solution is the exact thing I want however it does not work for me :(.

Comment: I had a typo I just fixed. I tested it on my computer and works perfectly for me now.

Answer (score 1):

Really don't need regex here -

```
    foreach ($arrayOfStrings as $row)
    {

        (if substr($row, 0, 1) == "H")
        {
            echo "Holding";
        } else {
            echo substr($row, 0, strpos($row, ":"));
        }

}
```

Comment: Actually I have to use regex

Comment: That doesn't make any sense - what are you trying to achieve where you can only use regex?